# Restful webservice client which accepts file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have created a web service which sents xml files whenever a folder is updated.I am able to receive that in my client but it is not happening dynamic. That is whenever the folder is updated the service is sending the file but the client is not taking the file
I have written a client side program  to accept file and write it to the disk. But it will accept the return type and will write only once. Can anybody tell what should I do to write it dyanmicaaly whenever the folder is updated My client side code is

```
   public class Clientservice {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://10.132.25.193:8082/ServerService/rest/Serverwebservice/get");
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            //FileMonitor ee=new FileMonitor(1000);

            InputStream is = uc.getInputStream();

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\298637\\Desktop\\Testing.xml"));
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                   fos.write(c);
                }


                is.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("FileStreamsTest: " + e);
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if English is your first language or not but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. Maybe if you can clarify what you're trying to do someone could help you out.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: I have created a restful web service which will take the latest file from a folder. This webservice will give the response in the form of inputstream. Whenevr I download a new file to this folder this web service will give the new file. My question is how should i write the client side program. The above program will write the file but whenever the web service is updated it should write the file.How this can be done??